# testing classes with constructor injection

Tags: typescript, jestjs, constructor-injection, inversifyjs

I have a class where multiple objects are injected using inversify's constructor injections.

```
//file Doctor.ts
import { inject } from 'inversify';

export class Doctor {
  private stetho: Stetho;
  private syringe: Syringe;

  constructor(
    @inject(Stetho) stetho: Stetho,
    @inject(Syringe) syringe: Syringe
  ) {
    this.stetho = stetho;
    this.syringe = syringe;
  }

  getName() {
    return "doctor";
  }
}
```

And I am testing this using `jest` using the following way.

```
//file test.ts
import { Doctor } from './Doctor';

describe("sample test", () => {
  test("test name", () => {
    const doctor = new Doctor();

    expect(doctor.getName()).toBe("doctor");
  });
});
```

The test runs fine, but the line with `new Doctor()` thrown an ts lint error stating that `Expected two arguments but received 0`.

Is there a way to avoid this without using `@ts-ignore` or using property injection?

Comment: Your doctor doesn't actually need those dependencies, you could remove them. If it was using them, you could inject test doubles with the appropriate interfaces and test the interactions.

Comment: for the sake of the example I have not shown them being used. Let's just assume that I need those objects.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I also have this problem and can't find info about this anywhere...